# SharePoint 2010: What are the Related Resources for Document Library items?

Tags: 2010, document-library, list-item

Could anyone please tell me what "Related Resources" means in context of Document Library?

I have an existing Document Library (created by Publishing feature) with MS Word files and some other file types, like PDF, in the library. When I navigate to the Document Library via Site Settings > Site Content and Structure > Documents, the menu bar gives me an option: "Show Related Resources." I want to know what these related resources are.

Additional information: When I create a new MS word document in the library, it does not get any related resources by default. Neither is there any such item under PDF document types. I have found only this article that touches on the topic; but it seems to be for Web Pages types: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/work-with-site-content-and-structure-HA010131723.aspx#BM7.